# how to select multiple columns with only one distinct column from joining two tables with all id's are UNIQUEIDENTIFIER using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, nhibernate

Following is my table structure:

```
create table Department(
    deptid [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] ROWGUIDCOL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Department_P_KEY PRIMARY KEY,
    departmentname varchar(100)
    )

create table Employee(
    empid [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] ROWGUIDCOL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Employee_P_KEY PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50), 
    city varchar(50),     
    deptid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    foreign key(deptid) references Department(deptid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
```

My issue is that when I select mutliple columns and apply `DISTINCT` on one column with all primary keys and foreign keys are `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` then that time query gives error message. my query and error as follows:

```
select distinct(Department.deptid),min(Employee.empid) as empid
from Employee
inner join Department on Department.deptid = Employee.deptid
group by Department.deptid
```

and Error message is :

> **Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for min operator.**

But if Primary key and foreign key was int then above query will execute successfully because min function support to integer but how can I select distinct record using uniqueidentifier key.

And Following is my Nhibernate query:-

```
EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = new EmployeeEntity();
            employeeEntity.DepartmentMaster = new DepartmentEntity();
            ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.ProjectionList();
            projectionList.Add(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property<EmployeeEntity>(x => x.DepartmentMaster)).WithAlias(() => employeeEntity.DepartmentMaster));
            projectionList.Add(Projections.Property<EmployeeEntity>(x => x.empid).WithAlias(() => employeeEntity.empid));

            IList<EmployeeEntity> query = null;
            query = NHSession.QueryOver<EmployeeEntity>()
            .Select(projectionList)
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<EmployeeEntity>()).List<EmployeeEntity>();
```

How can I execute distinct query in sql first as per above sql query?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the UniqueIdentifier to a string

```
select distinct(Department.deptid),min(CAST(Employee.empid AS NVARCHAR(36))) as empid
from Employee
inner join Department on Department.deptid = Employee.deptid
group by Department.deptid
```